# How exactly should I be linking in NPM modules?

Tags: html, django, npm

I'm updating all of my CSS and JS libraries, but I want to make sure I do it the right way this time. Let's take jQuery for example. First, I install with NPM.

```sh
$ npm i jquery # from project root
```

Then, I create symlinks to be included in my static directory.

```sh
$ cd home/static/lib/js # also from project root
$ ln -s ../../../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js
$ ln -s ../../../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
```

Next, in that same `js` directory, I generate hashsums.

```sh
$ openssl dgst -sha384 -binary jquery.js | openssl base64
/LjQZzcpTzaYn7qWqRIWYC5l8FWEZ2bIHIz0D73Uzba4pShEcdLdZyZkI4Kv676E
$ openssl dgst -sha384 -binary jquery.min.js | openssl base64
ZvpUoO/+PpLXR1lu4jmpXWu80pZlYUAfxl5NsBMWOEPSjUn/6Z/hRTt8+pR6L4N2
```

Finally, I add to the head of my Django template (HTML).

```html
<head>
  <!-- jQuery JS (compressed) -->
  <script
    src="{% static 'lib/js/jquery.min.js' %}"
    integrity="sha384-ZvpUoO/+PpLXR1lu4jmpXWu80pZlYUAfxl5NsBMWOEPSjUn/6Z/hRTt8+pR6L4N2"
  ></script>

  <!-- jQuery JS (uncompressed) -->
  <!-- <script
    src="{% static 'lib/js/jquery.js' %}"
    integrity="sha384-/LjQZzcpTzaYn7qWqRIWYC5l8FWEZ2bIHIz0D73Uzba4pShEcdLdZyZkI4Kv676E"
  ></script> -->
</head>
```

I comment out the uncompressed file to make page loading faster, but I leave the static URL for developers to see. It's hosted on the server, but it's not included in the head tag.

Are there any steps I'm missing? Should I include an external link to a CDN? Should I actually include the compressed file instead of just a comment of it?

Any clarification is helpful.

Comment: Hi, ultimately linking to the CDN is preferred especially as concerns page loading times. And all those comments then becomes irrelevant, especially if you are using version control. Or at least, you could split the `development` and `production` versions of your project.

Comment: Could you explain how those comments are irrelevant? They don't just disappear, do they? Even with source control? I do have separate `dev` and `master` branches in Git, but it hadn't occurred to me to separate node and CDN packages. So what should my upgrade process look like? Run `npm outdated` on my `dev` branch to check for newer versions, upgrade to the latest major version, see if that breaks things, and downgrade to latest minor version if it does? Then update `master` manually? How frequently should I do this? I have so many questions.

Comment: Ok, when any developer sees a file with `*.min`, they know it's compressed already. Also, since it's not expected for a developer to directly configure the `jquery` file (directly), then removing the "uncompressed" comments too becomes obvious, rigth?